# GraphQL GitHub Pagination

Tags: reactjs, api, github, graphql

I need to get, for example, elements 31 to 40 in the React component. To do this, I need to change "after" several times by setting the "endCursor" values from the previous query. How to do it?

```
query SearchRepositories($searchTerm: String!, $after: String) {
  search(query: $searchTerm, type: REPOSITORY, first: 10, after: $after) {
    repositoryCount
    pageInfo {
      endCursor
      hasNextPage
      hasPreviousPage
      startCursor
    }
    edges {
      node {
        ... on Repository {
          name
          url
          stargazerCount
          updatedAt
        }
      }
     }
   }
}
```

```
const handlePageClick = async (page: number): Promise<void> => {
  const newAfter = pageInfo?.startCursor + (page - 1) * 10;
  const { data }: ApolloQueryResult = await searchRepositories({
    variables: { searchTerm, first: 10, after: newAfter },
  });
  setAfter(newAfter);
};
```

Comment: Are you sure you can just add arbitrary values to the `startCursor`? I've seen those be opaque random strings. I'd expect you use the `endCursor` from the previous page to continue.

Comment: right. I use an endcursor of this kind from the last request - "Y3Vyc29yOjMw".
But in order for me to get page 91-100, I have to make 10 requests 1-10,11-20...81-90 - to get an endcursor? Is there an easy way to get 91-100 items at once? Github documentation gave nothing
the query Search Repositories query is linked to pagination. I click page 4 - I get the fourth dozen items.
or I can use the first = first * pageNumber parameter, but display 10 array elements from the end.

Comment: That's asking for an "offset". The cursor is used for sequential access only.

Comment: "message": "Field 'search' doesn't accept argument 'offset'"

Comment: You'll need to consult the documentation to see if such a feature is available. It may not be due to the complexities of pagination.